# Use of putStrLn to show result

Tags: haskell

I am using the Idone.com site and wanted to run this code but do not know the syntax putStrLn to compile from stdin Use this code but strip error.

```
main = putStrLn (show (sumaCifras x))
sumaCifras:: Int -> Int
sumaCifras x = div x 1000 + mod (div x 100) 10 + mod (div x 10) 10 + mod x 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler is having a problem, because you use x in main function, which isn't bound in this scope. At first you must read a value from input and then pass it to your function. You can do it in 2 ways.

More natural for people used to imperative languages is "do" syntax, in which it will look like that:

```
    main = do
        x <- getLine
        putStrLn (show (sumaCifras (read x :: Int)))
```

When you want to use x as Int, you must use "read" function with type signature, so compiler will know what to expect.

To write it in more functional way, you may use monad transformations, to pass it like that

```
    main = getLine >>= (\x -> putStrLn(show (sumaCifras (read x :: Int)))
```

The ">>=" operator will get result value from first monadic action (in here it is IO action of getting input) and apply it to function on the right (in here it is lambda function that reads input as Integer, applies your function and returns it to putStrLn, which prints it on the screen). "do" syntax is essentially just a syntactic sugar for this monadic operations, so it will not affect the execution or performance of program.

You can go one step further in writing it functionally by writing it totally point-free

```
    main = getLine >>= (putStrLn . show . sumaCifras . (read :: String -> Int))
```

Note that here you have type signature for read function, not for application of this function to argument, hence the String -> Int. In here first executed is the getLine function. Input obtained from it is then passed to the read, where it is casted to Int, next is sumaCifras, which then is casted to String by show and printed with putStrLn.

Comment: I try to run this code in idone.com according to the guidelines you gave me but pulls error saying
prog.hs:5:18: parse error on input `='

main = do
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn (show (sumaCifras (read x :: Int)))
    sumaCifras:: Int -> Int
    sumaCifras x = div x 1000 + mod (div x 100) 10 + mod (div x 10) 10 + mod x 10

Comment: This may be an indentation problem. Could you paste your full code with indentation? In your example you have indented definition of sumaCifras but it shouldn't be indented. Also you might want to add some brackets in the equation for sumaCifras, because in current form it will not yield results, you might expect.

Comment: How do I read two arguments from for example this function g :: Float -> Float -> Float
g n t = 2 - (7/(5**n*t))

with this main?
main = getLine >>= (putStrLn . show . g . (read :: String -> Float) (read :: String -> Float))

Comment: You mean you want to read 2 arguments from stdin and then pass them to your function? Best way would be to use arrows if you want to do it point-free, but without this shortest answer seems to be 
`main = strg <$> getLine <*> getLine >>= print
  where strg = flip ((flip (g . read)) . read)`

Comment: You may read arbitrary number of values and apply function to them with applicative style.
For example `f <$> getVal <*> getVal <*> getVal <*> getVal where getVal = read <$> getLine` where you use <$> to apply pure function to a value under a functor and then <*> to apply function under a functor to another value under a functor